# Calling unknown method: craft\models\Section::hasUrls() - Craft 3 upgrade

Tags: craft3, sections, deprecation

I am migrating a site from Craft 2 - Craft 3. In my sitemap template I have the following code;

```
{% for section in craft.sections.getAllSections() %}
  {# We only care about sections that have URLs #}
  {% if section.hasUrls %}
    <div class="article mb-8">
      <h2 class="pt-6 mb-4 border-bottom" id="{{  section.name|kebab }}">{{ section.name }}</h2>
      <ul class="ml-4 list-reset">
        {# Loop through each of its entries #}
        {% for entry in craft.entries.sectionId(section.id).limit(null) %}
          <li class="mb-2 text-sm"><a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="arrow--before">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am getting the error Calling unknown method: `craft\models\Section::hasUrls()`

I cannot find the equivalent or updated value in the Craft 3 docs. Can anyone advise as to how this should be rewritten or what I should use instead of if `section.hasUrls` in Craft 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Craft 3, `hasURL()` is part of a section's `siteSettings()` as a section exists in multiple sites and can have URLs in one site but not another.

If you are not using multi-sites, a drop-in replacement for your code would be:

```
{% for section in craft.sections.getAllSections() %}
  {% for sectionSettings in section.siteSettings %}
      {# We only care about sections that have URLs #}
      {% if sectionSettings.hasUrls %}
        <div class="article mb-8">
          <h2 class="pt-6 mb-4 border-bottom" id="{{  section.name|kebab }}">{{ section.name }}</h2>
          <ul class="ml-4 list-reset">
            {# Loop through each of its entries #}
            {% for entry in craft.entries.sectionId(section.id).limit(null) %}
              <li class="mb-2 text-sm"><a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="arrow--before">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```